# Is there a way to automatically close brackets, braces and parentheses in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, autocomplete

I'm looking for a way to have opened brackets, braces and parentheses automatically closed when typing in Chrome, exactly like how a code editor would. After googling I didn't see any extensions that would do it for me.